# Passing multiple passwords for SSHPASS in environment variables

Tags: ssh, sshpass

Hope everyone is safe and healthy. I am facing an issue in introducing multiple SSHPASS passwords in environment variables (/etc/profiles)

I am trying to SSH (using SSHPASS) to two different servers having different users/passwords.

Currently in my environment profile, i have stored the password as : export SSHPASS='xxxxxxx'

I need to store another password to SSH into the other server. Can anyone please direct me to a way out ?

Comment: FWIW: This is insecure and should not be done. You should use keyfiles for passwordless authentication instead.

Comment: Agreed. Consider using `ssh-keygen` to make multiple keypairs and populating `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` on the remote servers to avoid using passwords.

Comment: Read `man ssh_config ssh_ cooy_id`. It's eady to set up °ssh server1` , or `alias s1="ssh server1" to get logged in to (or simply run a command on `s1 uptime`), and get logged in as any usrr.